# Dynamically select variable in for loop

Tags: java, android

This seems very simple but I'm not understanding how to do this and haven't figured out how to phrase it for Google.  I have a set of 12 ImageViews declared in XML, so I want to declare them all in a for loop, using something like

```
for(int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    ImageView moles[i] = FindViewById(R.id.mole + i);
}
```

But I'm not understanding how to declare the argument for FindViewById.

Comment: You can't, unless you use reflection, which you don't want to. Is there some Android API that lets you pass the ID as a string instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you make a hard coded array of ids

```
int ids[] = {R.id.image1, R.id.imag2,...};
for(int i = 0; i < ids.size; i++) {
    ImageView moles[i] = FindViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

R.id.mole is dynamically generated by Android SDK. It is int, right, but you can't use as int because next one is not necessary previous+1.

If you use ids dynamically generated then assume they are random.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. But the closest you can get is by doing this

```
private static final int[] imageArray = {R.id.mole1, R.id.mole2, R.id.mole3, R.id.mole4, R.id.mole5};
private ImageView[] moles= new ImageView[idArray.length];
```

Then your for loop would look something like this

```
for (int i=1; i<=imageArray.length; i++) {
    moles [i] = (ImageView)findViewById(idArray[i]); // Fetch the view id from array
    ....
}
```

Comment: The final isn't needed, unless you want to pass the index to a Listener you declare inside this loop.  You can just use i